# Задача на динамическое программирование. Лесенка-2

Tags: c++, олимпиада, динамическое-программирование

Дана задача [условие и проверяющая система](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=329) :
Вова стоит перед лесенкой из N ступеней. На каждой из ступеней написаны произвольные целые числа. Первым шагом Вова может перейти на первую ступень или, перепрыгнув через первую, сразу оказаться на второй. Также он поступает и дальше, пока не достигнет N-ой ступени. Посчитаем сумму всех чисел, написанных на ступенях через которые прошел Вова.

Требуется написать программу, которая определит оптимальный маршрут Вовы, при котором, шагая, он получит наибольшую сумму.

Входные данные

Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит в первой строке натуральное число N – количество ступеней лестницы (2 ≤ N ≤ 1000). Во второй строке через пробел заданы числа, написанные на ступенях лестницы, начиная с первой. Числа, написанные на ступенях, не превосходят по модулю 1000.

Выходные данные

Выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT должен содержать в первой строке наибольшее значение суммы. Во второй строке должны быть записаны через пробел номера ступеней по возрастанию, по которым должен шагать Вова. Если существует несколько различных правильных маршрутов, то можно вывести любой из них.

Написал следующий код:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  stack<int> st;

  int n = 0, a[1000] = {0}, d[1000] = {0};

  cin >> n;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { cin >> a[i]; d[i] = a[i]; }

  for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] += max(a[i - 1], a[i - 2]);
  }

  st.push(n - 1);

  for(int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    if(a[i] - a[i - 1] == d[i]) st.push(i - 1);
    else if(a[i] - a[i - 2] == d[i - 1]) { st.push(i - 2); i--; }
  }

  cout << a[n - 1] << endl;

  while(st.size() > 0) {
    cout << st.top() + 1 << ' ';
    st.pop();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Однако он валит 6 тест, можете помочь найти и устранить ошибку, пожалуйста?

Comment: То ли я туплю, то ли нет, сложите все положительные числа - вот Вам максимум) ну а их индексы найдете....

Comment: @Maggot, а если подряд будут идти отрицательные числа? Тогда расчеты будут не верны. Задача похожа на матрицу смежности.

Comment: Навскидку, не разбираясь в коде - у вас явные вылеты за границу массива: `for(int i = 1; .... a[i - 2]);` - куда вы попадаете при `i=1`? Еще одно такое же обращение ниже.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev ага, ночь, голова не варит

Comment: @Harry исправил эту часть кода, теперь ошибка на тесте 5, а не на тесте 6
https://ideone.com/ZTbETQ

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko, забейте на эту задачу, она не такая простая как кажется, а её примеры решения и тесты могут не пройти если написать правильную программу. Составлял задачу явно не математик, в последовательности чисел `100 1000 -100 -200 -300 -50` уверен что у большинства принятых вариантов программ отработают не верно.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Забавно, обычно всегда - "это компилятор неправильно компилирует" :), сейчас уже и тесты неверные :) Это уже какая-то новая тенденция у начинающих :) Следующим шагом, наверное, будет неправильная математика. *"Это неправильные пчелы, и они делают неправильный мед!" (с) Пух*

Comment: @Harry, тесты - это ожидаемый результат. Что если он окажется не единственно верным? Или не окажется верным вовсе? Задачи, где есть вариант выбора с заменой переменной, не решаются 1 циклом. Тут нужно сначала полностью разобрать с математической точки зрения, а потом код писать. Вот о чем я.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev А я о том, что не надо людей, которые задают задачи и составляют проверяющие системы, считать глупее себя... Как и разработчиков компиляторов - *в данном случае это не к вам*, но очень уж задолбали частые вопросы "компилятор неверно компилирует мой код..." :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вот решение правильное...

```
void output(int m, const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)
{
    if (m < 0) return;
    if (b[m] == a[m] + b[m-1]) output(m-1,a,b);
    else output(m-2,a,b);
    cout << m+1 << " ";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> a(N);
    vector<int> b(N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cin >> a[i];

    b[0] = a[0];
    b[1] = max(a[1],a[0]+a[1]);
    for(int i = 2; i < N; ++i)
        b[i] = a[i] + max(b[i-1],b[i-2]);

    cout << b[N-1] << endl;
    output(N-1,a,b);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Посмотрите сами, что у вас не так...

P.S. У вас проблема в выводе (если, конечно, вы правильно исправили выход за пределы массива). Исправил, как мог... Выбрасываем `st.push(n - 1);` и пишем

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0;)
{
    st.push(i);
    if (i >= 1)
    {
        if (a[i] == d[i]+a[i-1]) { i--; }
        else { i -= 2; }
    } else break;
}

cout << a[n-1] << endl;

while(!st.empty())
{
    cout << st.top() + 1 << ' ';
    st.pop();
}
cout << endl;
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*, хотя что-то мне и этот вариант кажется подозрительным. Вот в своем уверен :)

P.P.S. Если "на краткость"...

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int a[1000],b[1000];
void o(int m){
if (m >= 0){o(m-2+(b[m]==a[m]+b[m-1]));cout<<m+1<<" ";}}
int N,i;
main(){
cin >> N;
for(;cin>>a[i];b[i]=a[i],i++);
if(a[0]>0)b[1]+=b[0];
for(i=1;++i<N;)b[i]+=max(b[i-1],b[i-2]);
cout<<b[--N]<< endl;
o(N);
}
```

:)

Comment: Спасибо, все верно :)
Попробовал исправить свое решение, изменив на ваш кусочек, все тесты прошло :)